# Angular Material select label not updating on ngrx change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngrx

I have an Angular Material select component with a custom label. This is provided by an async ngrx selector (prompt$) - simplified template below.

When prompt$ changes the paragraph is updated every time as would be expected, but the label in the select component **sometimes** isn't. However it is reliably updated the **first** time prompt$ is set.

What would cause this behaviour and is there a solution?

I've also tried passing the label as an input from a parent component and the result is the same.

```
<p>Async prompt test: {{prompt$ | async}}</p>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>
        {{prompt$ | async}}
    </mat-label>
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option>1</mat-option>
        <mat-option>2</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The value for prompt$ is updated as follows:

```
constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.prompt$ = this.store$.pipe(select(selectors.selectCustomPrompt));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code how the label value is modified

Comment: Thanks - have done

Comment: This is how you retrieve it from the store, but I'm interested in the code of the reducer

Comment: The issue you are describing is related to change detection (not NgRx), as the first usage of the observable is always updating. I suspect that the issue is related to content projection within form filed. Would you be able to create a stackblitz example with the issue?    

  https://medium.com/@pietmichal/angulars-content-projection-trap-and-why-you-should-consider-using-template-outlet-instead-cc3c4cad87c9